# Какой из вариантов частичной специализации класса лучше C++

Tags: c++

Я знаю, что есть несколько вариантов, но не понимаю, каким и когда нужно пользоваться.

Допустим, что я написал класс-обёртку для указателя, который магическим образом следит за вами как Большой Брат, чтобы вы не разыменовывали нулевой указатель, очищает за вами память после выхода из зоны видимости и т.д.

```
template <class Ty>
class super_puper_smart_pointer{
  publuc:
    super_puper_smart_pointer(Ty* ptr) 
      : _ptr(ptr) {
    }

  // ...

  private:
    Ty* _ptr;
};
```

И тут, вдруг, приходит осознание того, что вообще-то итераторы тоже было бы хорошо проверять. Например в таком коде

```
std::vector<int> m_numbers = {1, 2, 3};

auto first = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

// assert(find != v.end);

if(*first == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

закралась маленькая ошибка. Мы забыли проверить, что найденное значение это не конец последовательности.

Чтобы упростить жизнь, давайте напишем класс-обёртку для итераторов, который в конструкторе будет делать некоторые проверки.

Итак, подведя итоги, нам нужен класс-обёртка для указателей и для итераторов.

Чтобы можно было отличать одно от другого нам нужны:

- **std::is_pointer<...>**
- **is_iterator<...>**, реализация ниже

```
    template <class It>
    using iterator_category_t = typename ::std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;
    
    template <class Ty, class = void>
    inline constexpr bool is_iterator_v = false;
    
    template <class Ty>
    inline constexpr bool is_iterator_v<Ty, ::std::void_t<iterator_category_t<Ty>>> = true;
```

Остался последний шаг - реализовать класс-обертку с помощью частичной специализации.

### Вариант 1

```
// Реализация для указателя
template <class Ty, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<Ty>> = nullptr>
class super_puper_smart_pointer{
  publuc:
    super_puper_smart_pointer(Ty ptr) 
      : _ptr(ptr) {
      // какие-то проверки для указателя
    }

    template <class U>
    friend class super_puper_smart_pointer;

  private:
    Ty _ptr;
};

// Реализация для итератора
template <class Ty, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<Ty>> = nullptr>
class super_puper_smart_pointer{
  publuc:
    super_puper_smart_pointer(Ty it) 
      : _it(it) {
      // какие-то проверки для итератора
    }

    template <class U>
    friend class super_puper_smart_pointer;

  private:
    Ty _it;
};
```

### Вариант 2

```
// Частичное объявление
template <class Ty, class = void>
class super_puper_smart_pointer;

// Реализация для указателя
template <class Ty>
class super_puper_smart_pointer<std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<Ty>, int>>{
  publuc:
    super_puper_smart_pointer(Ty ptr) 
      : _ptr(ptr) {
      // какие-то проверки для указателя
    }

    template <class U>
    friend class super_puper_smart_pointer;

  private:
    Ty _ptr;
};

// Реализация для итератора
template <class Ty>
class super_puper_smart_pointer<Ty, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<Ty>, int>>{
  publuc:
    super_puper_smart_pointer(Ty it) 
      : _it(it) {
      // какие-то проверки для итератора
    }

    template <class U>
    friend class super_puper_smart_pointer;

  private:
    Ty _it;
};
```

### Вопросы:

1. Почему где-то нужно писать `std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<Ty>> = nullptr`, а где-то `std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<Ty>, int>`
2. Как лучше писать?
3. **Научите, как правильно писать, потому что я даже в вопросе написал с ошибками, я не понимаю этот синтаксис**
4. Ещё то же самое можно сделать через void_t (по-моему), как?
5. Когда писать `= nullptr`
6. Когда писать `enable_if`, а когда `enable_if_t`

Comment: когда писать  функцию, когда писать класс, когда писать  то, когда писать .....?  Это не вопрос, а просьба написать целую книгу.  Задавайте конкретные вопросы.  Какой  из вариантов лучше?.. Ни один, потому что  и сама задумка и реализация   не  блещет смыслом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше не делать специализациями разные вещи. Так, `vector<bool>` часто приводят пример как ошибки, несмотря на то, что динамический битсет в принципе контейнер нужный.

Проверка итератора и проверка указателя -- разные проверки, то есть специализации будут слишком разные!

Проверки итераторов лучше не прикручивать извне, а делать на стороне реализации. Так они имеют больше доступа к деталям реализации.

Реализации STL обычно уже имеют все эти проверки в дебаг режиме. Лучший способ сделать свои такие проверки, если готовые не подходят -- сделать свои контейнеры STL.

---

`std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<Ty>>* = nullptr` и `std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<Ty>, int> = 0` -- одно и тоже, вкусовщина. Это способ убить специализацию через SFINAE, если условие ложно

`void_t` -- это другое, это способ убить специализацию через SFINAE, если подстановка неуспешна. Например, так проверяют наличие метода.

`enable_if`, как и прочие не `_t` версии функций над типами -- более неудобные варианты, которые нужны были до появления `using` в контексте template typedef.

Comment: "Лучше не делать специализациями разные вещи. Так, vector<bool> часто приводят пример как ошибки, несмотря на то, что динамический битсет в принципе контейнер нужный." - Понял, звучит логично, так что соглашусь с вами и сделаю просто 2 разных класса. Благодарю вас!